# How to insert into a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, insert-query

```
Table Name: free_meals_bill

punch_date                   employee_id  employee_name product_name
2021-02-22 12:15:50.086471   123456       john          Variety Rice - Curd - Rs.35
2021-02-22 12:19:50.086472   234456       marry         Variety Rice - Curd - Rs.35
2021-02-22 12:22:50.086473   355456       peter         Variety Rice - Curd - Rs.35
```

Before inserting into "free_meals_bill" table, I want to check that per employee_id only one punch is allowed.
For example, if john (employee id 123456) is already in the free_meals_bill then again for the same date, john data should not be insert again into the "free_meals_bill" table.

Query:

```
 insert into free_meals_bill (punch_date,employee_id,employee_name,product_name)
 Values ('2021-02-22 10:15:50.086471',123456,'john','Variety Rice - Curd - Rs.35')
 SELECT
 employee_id,
 COUNT(*) as count,
 date_trunc('day',punch_date) as day
 FROM bill_item
 WHERE punch_date>= CURRENT_DATE
 GROUP BY employee_id, day 
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be better solved by adding a unique constraint on the date (without time) and employee_id?

Comment: not just solved, IMO if you want something unique, you should always use unique constraint, it block every potential miss fire and any bug (which will always happen no matter how careful both user and engineer are) that might lead to unwanted duplicate.

Comment: I don't understand why your `select` retrieves rows from `bill_item` if you want to check if the data to be inserted already exists in `free_meals_bill`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  a NOT EXISTS condition to check if the to be inserted values already exist:

```
insert into free_meals_bill (punch_date, employee_id, employee_name, product_name)
select *
from (
   values (date '2021-02-22 10:15:50.086471',123456,'john','Variety Rice - Curd - Rs.35')
) as t(punch_date, employee_id, employee_name, product_name
where not exists (SELECT *
                  FROM free_meals_bill bi
                  WHERE bi.punch_date::date = t.punch_date::date
                    AND bi.employee_id = t.employee_id)
```

But if you only allow one row per `(employee_id, punch_date)` you should create a unique constraint or index

```
create unique index only_one_meal_per_day
  on free_meals_bills ( (punch_date::date), employee_id);
```

Then you can do:

```
insert into free_meals_bill (punch_date, employee_id, employee_name, product_name)
values (date '2021-02-22 10:15:50.086471',123456,'john','Variety Rice - Curd - Rs.35')
on conflict ((punch_date::date), employee_id)
do nothing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement has wrong column sequence, it should be the same sequence with your insert statement. date,id,name,product. And, should be the same number of columns too.

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e71cce99ec979e741a6090afb32f2b0e)

1. You cannot use `VALUES` and `SELECT` in one `INSERT` statement. The `SELECT` statement replaces the `VALUES` part
2. You can use `EXISTS` to check for occurrences.

   ```
   INSERT INTO free_meals_bill (punch_date,employee_id,employee_name,product_name)
   SELECT
       *
   FROM bill_item
   WHERE punch_date >= CURRENT_DATE
       AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM free_meals_bill WHERE employee_id = bill_item.employee_id
       );
   ```

Note: I used `*` selector here, because in my example `bill_item` has the same columns as `free_meals_bill`. You have to adapt this to your real used case, of course, if it doesn't fit to something like this (depending on how `bill_item` actually looks like):

```
SELECT
    punch_date,
    employee_id,
    employee_name,
    product_name
...
```

---

**Edit**:

To avoid such duplication by table design you should think about adding a `UNIQUE` contraint to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE free_meals_bill ADD CONSTRAINT my_unique_constraint UNIQUE (employee_id);
```

This prevents `INSERT` statements from inserting duplicate records automatically, you don't need to do this with `SELECT` statements

Comment: i dont know how to insert could you please guide me

Comment: What exact is your problem? Did you see the fiddle link? There you can see the demo...

Comment: I want to check before insert, if exists means dont want to insert else insert

Comment: Once more: Did you look at the fiddle: I shows: First run inserted the records, because nothing was in there. When inserting the second time, this results in nothing: No second entry was added. So: EXISTS checks if there is already a fitting record in the table, if not the record is inserted.

Comment: I added another way, which should be taken to increase the consistency of your database: Using a UNIQUE constraint on the table instead using a SELECT statement...

Comment: @pythoncoder Did this help? I'd appreciate if you could upvote the answer since it pointed out two possible solutions. Please don't forget to UPVOTE every answer which was helpful in any way (pointing out a good idea, shows a way to a possible solution, ...). This honors the time and effort the repliers invested into your problem and motivates them to do so. If one answer completely solves your problem, please ACCEPT it additionally to close the question :)